# Double forward slash in url breaks router

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, express, url-routing

This is my React router:

```
function redirect(nextState, replaceState) {
      replaceState({ nextPathName: nextState.location.pathname }, '/')
    }

const routes = (
    <Route component={App}>
      <Route path="/" component={Lead}/>
      <Route path="*" onEnter={redirect}/>
    </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

Every route entered except for '/' gets redirected to '/'

The problem is: if the user enters ***mywebsite.com//***
The server will not be able to serve static assets and the website will appear without JS nor CSS

How to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Add This At The End of `<Switch>` before `<Route path="*" >`

```
<Redirect from="//*" to="/*" />
```